# E=F(E^p) implies extension is algebraic

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, galois-theory

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $p$ and $E/F$ be a finitely generated field extension such that $E=F(E^p)$. Then show that $E/F$ is algebraic.

I have proven it in case $E$ is singly generated over $F$ but the general case seems difficult to prove.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: As a starting point, I would try looking at Saunders Mac Lane's "Modular Fields I". I don't know whether the answer to your question is there, but it contains a good deal of interesting information about separating transcendence bases that may help.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look at it!